Signature field on PDF form doesn't work on web browsers but works on adobe reader
Hi I wonder if I can get help with my PDF form it's working well on adobe reader but when I use web browser like chrome or Firefox the signature field diaper or spear like textbox
I tried to convert it to web from its works. But I need it to upload to Moodle activity.

For us to help you with your PDF you have to share it with us, don't you?
